# React Native Android production release still behaving like a development release

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am attempting to build a signed Android APK from my React Native application. I have followed the official documentation and numerous third party sources to get code signing set up properly, and it comes down to running this command to generate the signed APK...

```
$ cd android/
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

The APK is signed properly and placed at `app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`. I've even managed to successfully upload this APK to the Play Store through an internal testing track.

The problem is that when the app first launches, it asks the user to grant overlay permissions and displays a message in a toast explaining that the permissions are required for React Native's debugging tools to function. Fixes for this are [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347562/how-to-turn-off-overlay-permission-on-android) in a few places, but those fixes don't seem to work because the app doesn't seem to understand that it's not in development mode.

[image: React Native Android Overlay Permissions]

The app also displays a stack trace in the traditional React Native "big red error" box whenever a runtime error occurs in the app, rather than crashing or swallowing the error which is the behavior I see when building the app on iOS in production mode. When this happens the error mentions being unable to connect to the packager.

Pressing `Cmd + M` or shaking the device opens the React Native debug menu. `process.env.NODE_ENV` also has a value of `development`.

When investigating, I've found that `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is `false`, as expected. The app does use a packaged bundle generated at build time, and operates independently from the React Native packager.

I've attempted to manually create the `index.android.bundle` using `react-native bundle` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977835/react-native-android-release-apk-is-debug-not-release), but the bundle file seems to get recreated and replaced when running `./gradlew assembleRelease`. It's as if the `--dev` flag isn't getting set to `false` when `react-native bundle` is being ran.

Here are my Node, React, and React Native versions...

```
Node:          v8.11.3
React:         v16.2.0
React Native:  v0.51
```

My best guess is that despite the fact that it's being built in production mode, React is not getting the memo and is instead operating in development mode. Where should I look to see if everything is configured properly? Are there React Native bundle generation settings that might have gotten messed up?

Comment: because maybe you are testing it in the emulator! I tested my release on the same device it had some dev mode on!   but when gave that released apk to another android phone! it worked just fine! like peas and carrots

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this spans across multiple devices, computers, and even when the app is downloaded from the Play Store by people who have never had it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible the override for `getUseDeveloperSupport` in your `MainApplication.java` is incorrect.

The issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17522) indicates that this may be hard-coded to true. If that is the case, change the return value to `BuildConfig.DEBUG` instead.

Comment: Thank you random stranger, that was exactly the issue!